# Is preferential oxidation/reduction at electrodes only dependent on the reduction potential or is it also dependent on kinetics?

Tags: electrochemistry, kinetics

It is commonly taught that in electrochemical cells where there are 2 different chemical species that can be oxidised/reduced, species with more positive actual reduction potentials (concentration being considered as well as standard reduction potential) are preferentially reduced at cathodes, and species with more negative actual reduction potentials are preferentially oxidised at anodes.

It appears to me that, theoretically speaking, this need not always be the case, since reduction potentials predict thermodynamics, not kinetics. Therefore, it seems plausible that a case could arise where: 2 species are present at the anode of an electrolytic cell; one species has a more negative reduction potential, but for some reason (charge, hydration shell etc) has much slower oxidation kinetics compared to the other species, which has a more positive reduction potential but has much more rapid kinetics, causing the species with a more positive reduction potential to be oxidised preferentially.

Is this reasoning flawed, and if not, is there such a case in real life experiments?

Comment: You more or less reinvented the nature of polarography. If the rate of reaction kinetics or diffusion for the "first choice" is slow enough, it allows electrode potential to be externally raised or lowered enough to start the less preferred choice.

Comment: @Poutnik Meh, looks like he only got next to overpotential.

Comment: BTW OP should make clear it's about kinetics already in the title, not end of the body of question.

Comment: That's my bad, will edit, thanks

Comment: The reasoning is fine, there are huge amounts of examples. For anodic reactions one can think about how a lot of metals actually form chlorine rather than oxygen in aqueous sodium chloride solutions. For reduction reactions there are a lot of examples that are currently hot topic, like CO2 reduction to a lot of species which some are thermodynamically preferred over hydrogen gas formation. Same with ammonia formation from nitrogen etc.

Comment: Thanks everyone, will read up on the mentioned concepts